# MongoDB C++ driver -- Passing Query object by reference raises error when subsequently using its sort

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-c

Windows 7 64 SP1 --
MongoDB 2.2.0-rc2 --
Boost 1.42 --
MS VS 2010 Ultimate --
C++ driver

I've written this function:

`void printQuery(DBClientConnection &c, std::string &dc, const Query &qu = BSONObj(), std::string sortby = "" )`

This fragment:

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor;
cursor = c.query(dc,qu.sort(sortby))
```

raises the error:

`error C2663: 'mongo::Query::sort' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer.`

`sort (const string &field, int asc=1)` should be the applicable overload. I believe this is something to do with using `const Query&` with its member function `sort`. But if I change it to `Query&` without the `const`, then my parameter initialization `= BSONObj()` raises:

`cannot convert from 'mongo::BSONObj' to 'mongo::Query &'`

If I pass by value, then it compiles fine.

Is there a way to avoid either of the errors (beside passing by value)? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why you use default value for query?

Comment: Because I want to be able to call it without a Query so that it will print all documents in the collection by default. I did rewrite using overloaded functions but came across the same issue.

Comment: I rewrote using overloaded functions without the `const` but came across a similar issue -- I could no longer pass BSONObjs --`mongo::BSONObj` could not be converted to `mongo::Query &` All of the Query objects passed just fine.

Answer (score 1):

David Hows [at MongoDB-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/qCX7B8AYiZs) walked me through the solution:

Instead of `const Query &qu = BSONObj()`, use `Query &qu = Query()`.

1. I was getting an error using `const` "because sort will change the value of the query object - which is defined as a constant." So I dropped it.
2. Using BSONObj() as the default is problematic because I'm not "creating a new object but assigning a new BSONObj into a variable for a Query object, nothing new is being created thus no constructor call."

So I used Query() instead. `if ( qu.obj == BSONObj() )` works for testing if qu is empty.

My final function is:

`void printQuery(DBClientConnection &c, const string &dc, Query &qu = Query(), const string &sortby = "" )`

I couldn't make the `DBClientConnection` qualified as `const`. It raised the `no legal conversion for 'this' pointer` when using c.query and

`C2662: 'mongo::DBClientWithCommands::count' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const mongo::DBClientConnection' to 'mongo::DBClientWithCommands &' Conversion loses qualifiers`

when using c.count. So I kept it unqualified.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sorting the cursor and not on `qu`, which I presume to be your BSON query.  eg.

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor;
cursor = c.query(dc,qu).sort(sortby)
```

Check out [http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415#C%2B%2BTutorial-Sorting](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415#C%2b%2bTutorial-Sorting) for more information.

Comment: It appears to sort on the query:

`auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("tutorial.persons", QUERY( "age" << age ).sort("name") );`

To sort on the query, it would read:

`auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("tutorial.persons", QUERY( "age" << age )).sort("name");` I changed my code to read `cursor = c.query( dc,qu).sort(sortby);` & it raised `error C2039: 'sort' : is not a member of 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>'` Am I missing something fundamental? I thought sort was a helper function of the Query object.

Comment: "To sort on the query, it would read:" should be "To sort on the cursor, it would read:"